# Experiencing Android Audio Stuttering during Screen Lock/Wake

Tags: android, audio, opensl

I'm working on an Android app centered around audio playback and I'm experiencing some erratic behavior (audio stuttering and hiccups) that I suspect might be inherent to certain devices, OS versions or perhaps the native buffer size of the device.

About my implementation - I'm in need of low latency so I'm processing my audio in OpenSL ES callbacks and using a fairly small buffer size of 128 samples to enqueue the buffers. I am doing mp3 decoding during the callback, but with my ring buffer size, I do not need to decode during every callback cycle.

I'm using a remote testing service to gauge audio playback quality on a variety of devices and OS versions and here's a few examples of the inconsistencies I'm finding.

- Samsung Galaxy S4 w/ Android 4.4 - no audio playback issues
- Samsung Galaxy S4 w/ Android 4.3 - user experiences audio drop-outs/stuttering when locking/un-locking the device
- Samsung Galaxy Note 2 w/ Android 4.1.2 - no issues
- Samsung Galaxy Note 2 w/ Android 4.3 - audio drop-outs during playback and stuttering when locking/unlocking screen.

Personally, I have a Galaxy S3 w/ 4.1.2 and a Nexus 5 with 4.4 and don't ever experience these issues. I also have a few older 2.3.7 devices where these issues do not occur (2010 Droid Incredible, LG Optimus Elite).

I am fairly confident that I'm not over-working the processor since I can get this running on older, Gingerbread devices just fine.

My questions:

1. If I raise my base SDK to 4.2, I can detect native buffer size from the hardware and use some multiple of this during my buffer queue callbacks. Would this make much of a difference in cases where stuttering and drop-outs are problematic especially during screen lock?
2. Is there a known bug with Android 4.3 where audio playback suffers,
   especially during screen lock actions? Is this possibly just a Samsung issue?
3. Are there other ways of improving performance to avoid this problem? I absolutely need OpenSL ES for my app.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey rmigneco! I know this is a 2 yr old question but did you find a way to improve the performance? I'm also encountering these issues but with OS 5.0 and above. I'm getting distortion/stuttering on certain Androids even when I set my OpenSL configuration with the `AudioManager`'s sample rate and buffer size property. Thanks!

Comment: @yun.cloud Unfortunately I moved on from that project and am no longer working on Android development. I don't think we ever completely solved the issue but had identified a set of devices that were problematic. Good luck troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Thanks~ I actually figured out how to fix the dropouts/stuttering when I lock the device but definitely still get occasional blips.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing buffer size solves some problems regarding distortion and noise. Yes, you can detect native buffer size from the hardware when your SDK is above 4.2 with this:

```
String size = audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
```

But yet another approach to get the minimum buffer size for Audio Record is:

```
int minForAudioRecord = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
```

And for Audio Playback:

```
int minForAudioTrack = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
```

If your SDK version is greater than or equal to 4.2, then you can have preferred sample rate for your audio.

```
String rate = audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE);
```

I've found samsung devices are the worst while dealing with these things because each device has different approach to deal with audio drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I feel like AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER and audioTrack.getMinBufferSize aren't necessarily referring to the same device constant. For example, on a Nexus 5 the former gives me 240 samples while the latter gives 7056 bytes. Converting this at 2 bytes/sample and 2 channel stereo gives 1764 samples, which is a weird large number and not a multiple of 240. I'll keep trying with Output_Frames_Ber_Buffer and hopefully I can get my hands on a device that misbehaves in the meantime.